# React-Native “react-native run-ios” on a mac hackintosh

Tags: ios, react-native

I installed a fresh react-native app.I keep getting the below error when I ran "react-native run ios

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   132    0   132    0     0    199      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   199

 45 6847k   45 3121k    0     0  30498      0  0:03:49  0:01:43  0:02:06 23307
 98 6847k   98 6724k    0     0  33096      0  0:03:31  0:03:27  0:00:04 16281
100 6847k  100 6847k    0     0  32939      0  0:03:32  0:03:32 --:--:-- 29880

curl: Saved to filename 'double-conversion-1.1.5.tar.gz'

Unpacking /Users/dev/.rncache/double-conversion-1.1.5.tar.gz...

Incorrect hash:

333dca13f4d16419d02d914c1b645477d40fd725 ?/Users/dev/.rncache/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz

Retrying...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   609    0   609    0     0   1170      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1168
```

Comment: Try deleting the `~/.rncache` folder and trying again.

Comment: how install hackintosh?

Comment: @Man Start here https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/im-new-to-everything-where-do-i-start.104542/

Comment: @JagjotSingh it worked for me